# Flutter decompressed byte array to multiple files

Tags: flutter, dart

i’m trying to extract all the files contained in .pak compressed file, i have decompressed the files with lz4 library (through [es_compression package](https://github.com/instantiations/es_compression) but i’m stucked to save each file of .pak, now i have a byte array of decompressed .pak file, it contain's differents files, how i can read each file contained? Thanks!